# Singapore and surroundings

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, hiking, singapore

I will visit Singapore in January and in March. What would you suggest me to visit in order to see nice nature/wildlife/birds or similar things. How about Malaysia on a daytrip?
Sumatra in Indonesia for perhaps a two-daytrip?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, your question is very broad as you're asking about activities within Singapore as well as other places to visit. I'd advise you to split them into different questions, and make the questions more focussed.